# Any online software to calculate pvalue of Fisher exact test?

Tags: software, fishers-exact-test

I would like to do a one-sided Fisher´s exact test for an analysis. I have not any statistic software to obtain the pvalues (no SAS, no SPSS). The 2x2 tables are of this type:

Do you know any online statistical software to calculate the pvalues? I have tried with some of them but the results indicate pvalue<0.0001 but I need to know the exact number.
The 2x2 tables are of this type:

[image]

Thanks a lot in advanced!

Comment: See answer and comments at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72553/which-statistic-test-to-used which already give implicit and explicit answers, namely download R.

Comment: @Nick I deleted the first part of your comment in the spirit of http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/behavior. I know you were helping, but we should take care to consider the feelings of newcomers who are not used to the site and the necessarily abbreviated conversations that occur in comments.

Comment: Why do you need a p-value more exact than <.0001? I could have seen why you might have wanted an exact p-value if it had been > .001, but is there a reason why you want to be more precise than "<0.0001" ?

Comment: I need to obtain the exact pvalue to be able to compare different functional groups of genes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft research have an online tool [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/mscompbio/fisherexacttest). You can also download an Excel add-in from [here](http://www.real-statistics.com/free-download/).

Your result according to the Microsoft tool is 6.511E-017.

Comment: (+1) I think this is better than suggesting to the OP to download R. I was not aware of this online resource.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jamie and Patrick. The Microsoft tool works perfectly and now I can calculate all the pvalues :)